# CWM recovery Nandroid Backup

Tags: rom-flashing, clockworkmod-recovery, scripts

Is there any way to create a Nandroid backup inside **CWM recovery**, by using the `/cache/recovery/extendedcommand` file?

<sub>(This file supports all the commands a normal `updater-script` file supports inside a flashable zip).</sub>

---

**Edit:**
I know it's easier to do this with use of TWRP. However, I am developing an app that takes backups automatically. I want it to support both CWM and TWRP if possible.

Comment: Isn't there any TWRP image available for the device? It is easy to use OpenRecoveryScript with TWRP.

Comment: @Firelord Yes, I know that it's possible to use TWRP. However, I am developing an Android app that should do all of this automatically, and also would like to support CWM.